# Generic history management of business objects in C#

Tags: c#, history

I would like to implement something like this in my Web API application:

- each transaction which modifies data should be "logged"
- the log should be done in the business layer, and could be stored in either a regular SQL database which currently stores the data, or in a some sort of a NoSQL database.
- each transaction in the log file basically stores who performed the transaction, when, what transaction, and the old/new data.
- this could be used to view the change history of objects, and could help in implementing undo/rollback.

My questions are:

- does this exist as a library/framework somewhere?
- does this have a name?
- are there any obvious flaws I'm missing?

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DbContext, in that case your can override *SaveChanges* method. like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{    
    foreach (var entityState in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        // loggin here
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or you can use [EFTracingProvider](http://efwrappers.codeplex.com/)